# PHP if statement assistance

Tags: php

I am doing a lookup in a certificate and need to use an if statement to determine how to set a variable

This is the path I am trying to check. In this case it ends with ['utf8String'].

> $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][0][0]['value']['utf8String'];

However, the last [] could either be ['utf8String'] or it could be ['printableString'] and based on whatever it is I want to set that as a variable.. I tried with the following code but it doesn't work. Need some advice.

```html
if ($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][0][0]['value'] == "utf8String") {
$CN = $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][0][0]['value']['utf8String'];
} else if ($cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][0][0]['value'] != "utf8String") {
$CN = $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][0][0]['value']['printableString'];
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking the key not value. Try with -

```
if (array_key_exists('utf8String', $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][0][0]['value'])) {
    // do what you want
} else if (array_key_exists('printableString', $cert['tbsCertificate']['subject']['rdnSequence'][0][0]['value'])) {
    // do what you want
}
```

If you are looping through the array then please change the array.

Comment: Thank you for understanding my issue better than how I explained it. Your code works exactly as requested. Appreciate your assistance!